# How to give xpath in module.exports using mocha javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm using mocha with nodejs and want to use the xpath defined in one test file (verification.js)and use it in another file (test.js).How should i give define the xpath as it contains single quotes inside single quotes ?

I have tried giving \ before start and end of the code, but when i run the program am getting error "cannot read the property xyz"

verifications.js file

```
module.exports={
    loginLocation : 'xpath("//span[text()=\'LOGIN\']")',
}
```

test.js file

```
const value=require('./verifications.js');
var By=webdriver.By;
before(function(){
    driver.findElement(By.value.loginLocation).click();

});
```

I want to pass xpath from one file to another

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

fileA.js:

```
module.exports.loginLoc = 'xpath("//span[text()=\'LOGIN\']")';
```

fileB.js:

```
const fileA = require('fileA');
console.log('check out', fileA.loginLoc);
```

Comment: I have tried above format.Got the error   TypeError: Cannot read property 'usernameLocation' of undefined